# SQL grouping similar values together

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am having a problem to group data. I have used the group by clause all the while, but this time I want to group similar valued data together.
The need is I have some jobs which have sequence numbers associated. If I can group the jobs together which have more or less the same sequence numbers then I can run a lesser number of jobs.

The data I have is like this.

```
    JobID         Sequence
    A01            8               
    A01            6
    A01            10 
    A02            5
    A02            10
    A02            4
    A02            2
    A03            8
    A03            3
    A03            6
    A03            10
    A04            5
    A04            4
    A04            2
    A04            9
    A04            10
```

From the above data it can be seen that A02 and A04 have more in common and A01 and A03 have more in common.

What query should be done to get similar data group together as below to group A02 and A04 together and A01 and A03 together, the order on the sequence column being immaterial.

```
    JobID         Sequence
    A01            8               
    A01            6
    A01            10 
    A03            8
    A03            3
    A03            6
    A03            10
    A02            5
    A02            10
    A02            4
    A02            2
    A04            5
    A04            4
    A04            2
    A04            9
    A04            10
```

Thanks for the time

david

PS - More explanation.

In the above list JobID 
A01 contains sequence (8,6,10)
A02 contains sequence (5,10,4,2)
A03 contains sequence (8,3,6,10)
A04 contains sequence (5,4,2,9,10)

So Job A01 and Job A03 have similar sequence numbers and Job A02 and Job A03 have similar sequence numbers. I want to group them based on similar sequence numbers
There are many other jobs which have sequences which might match some other job's sequence numbers. I just included 4 jobs to keep the list small.

Comment: have you tried writing the sql query, and does it work?

Comment: yes, i did it does not give me the expected output though "select jobid,sequence from jobtable group by sequence,jobid"

Comment: Do you just want to order your data by `JobID` in the order A01,A03,A02,A04?
Are those the only JobIDs - or are there more.. A05.. B01.. Z99 ?

Comment: Am I reading this right, that you effectively want a custom order by on the JobID field? E.g. A01, followed by A03, A02 & A04?

Comment: You want to group by "similar" data. What do you mean by "similar"? How do you calculate a "similar" value between two `JobID`?

Comment: Please see added PS to original post, I have added more explanation. my mistake on not being clear about "similar" data

Comment: @Ghita so a query will not be able to do it?

Comment: `A02` and `A04` has one value in common with `A03` Does that mean that it is a tie between `A02` and `A04`? Could `A04` be ordered before `A02`?

Comment: hmm... a good query may be close to what you want.

Comment: @Eriksson A04 coming before A02 is just and added bonus :-) I don't want to push it too much.

Comment: The definition of similar sequence should be tighter: in terms of what? `A` and `B` is similar if `A` is a  subset of `B` or vice versa?

Comment: @cctan - If there are 3 sets A,B and C (here a set is a job with sequences). Similar means the sets which have the most number of common elements.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little more complex of a problem then I feel like thinking all the way through right now, but I'll give you an idea to start with and maybe someone else can help you complete it...

Join the table to itself like so:

```
Select  A.JobID, A.Sequence, Count(*) 

from    TheTable A join
        TheTable B on A.JobID <> B.JobID and A.Sequence = B.Sequence

group by A.JobID
```

I haven't tested that so there could be typos, but you get the idea hopefully.  Notice you're joining where the job is not the same, but the sequence is.

Comment: FYI, it's most definitely possible to achieve what you're after with pure sql, but it's going to be hard to understand and not very maintainable code.  I would highly recommend utilizing a real programming language like C# (or your language of choice) to solve this problem unless you just enjoy a good brain teaser.

Comment: My first choice was C# but it was too slow, so I just want to see if it can be done at the db.

Comment: @davidmichell How many records?  I'll keep this in the back of my mind and prolly in a week or so I'll have a light bulb moment about it.  Will let you know if/when that happens :)

Comment: @Moore there are about 3 million rows.

Comment: @davidmichell In your C# solution, were you loading all the data into memory before working with it?  It's going to be ridiculously slow if it has to keep calling the database over and over again, but if you just call the db once to load all the data before working with it then I would think C# should be able to handle this over 3,000,000 in a timely manner.

Answer (score 2):

Just inferring from other answers... something that may help.

Here you have for every two jobids how simmilar are:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c28be/9

```
Create table Data(Job nvarchar(10), seq int);

insert into data
SELECT 'A01' ,8  UNION ALL
SELECT 'A01',6 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A01',10 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A02',5 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A02',10 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A02',4 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A02',2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A03',8 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A03',3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A03',6 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A03',10 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A04',5 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A04',4 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A04',2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A04',9 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A04',10;


select 
  d1.job as j1, 
  d2.job as j2, 
  count(*) cnt 
from Data d1 inner join Data d2 on (d1.seq = d2.seq and d1.job < d2.job)
group by d1.job, d2.job
;
```

Comment: this one even removes the duplicates  (a02,a04) = (a04,a02). so just (a02,a04) would be enough. this query does this too. thanks Ghita

Answer (score 1):

Building on Brandon Moores answer:

Data setup:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (JobId nvarchar(10), Sequence int)
INSERT INTO @Data(JobId, Sequence)
SELECT 'A01',8 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A01',6 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A01',10 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A02',5 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A02',10 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A02',4 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A02',2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A03',8 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A03',3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A03',6 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A03',10 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A04',5 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A04',4 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A04',2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A04',9 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A04',10 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A05',100
```

Find totals of all sequences each JobID has in common, order those by most to least, output all the data from each JobId depending on that order:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  A.JobID, A.Sequence, Count(*) AS [SequencesInCommon]
    FROM    @Data A 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        @Data B on A.JobID <> B.JobID and A.Sequence = B.Sequence
    GROUP BY A.JobID, A.Sequence
),    
cte2 AS (
    SELECT JobID, SUM(SequencesInCommon) AS Total 
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY JobID
)    
SELECT  d.JobId, d.Sequence
FROM    cte2 c
INNER JOIN @Data d on c.jobID = d.JobID
ORDER BY c.Total ASC, c.JobID ASC
```

Gives:

```
JobId      Sequence
---------- -----------
A05        100
A01        8
A01        6
A01        10
A03        8
A03        3
A03        6
A03        10
A02        5
A02        10
A02        4
A02        2
A04        5
A04        4
A04        2
A04        9
A04        10

(17 row(s) affected)
```

Should do it :)

Comment: he wants to determine that order. He doesn't know it before the query.

Comment: @FlorinGhita - I've edited my answer based on BrandonMoores answer above

Comment: Ok, now it's a valid try :) and a +1 from me :)

Comment: Cool Thanks Ed that definitely does it.

Comment: If I add a another row to the table say ('A05',100), then this row does not appear in the result. I figured out that is because sequence no. 100 is not in common with any other jobID. What should I do to make even this row appear in the final result. I tried to do select jobid, sequence from data except ; with cte as .... but I am getting an error "Incorrect syntax near ;"

Comment: @davidmichell `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in the first CTE - I've updated my answer, should work now - note the results set is ordered least to most Sequences in common